# Meteor's accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 {{loginButtons}} not displaying

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, meteorite

After installing `bootstrap-3` and `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`, the `ui-accounts` login widget did not appear when `{{ loginButtons }}` is used. Instead a `<div>` is found in its place but no widget is visible.

Are there additional steps that is missing for the widget to be displayed?

**Adding Bootstrap 3 packages**

```
mrt add bootstrap-3
mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
```

**main.html**

```
<body>
  {{> header}}
</body>

<template name="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Bootstrap 3 App</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li>{{ loginButtons }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div>
</template>
```

**Output of {{ loginButtons}}**

```
<div id="login-buttons" class="login-buttons-dropdown-align-right"></div>
```

[image]

---

### Update

**Misaligned `{{ loginButtons }}`**

[image]

**Properly aligned example in docs**

[image]

Comment: Have you added an accounts package? e.g `meteor add accounts-password`? or a third party oauth provider like `meteor add accounts-facebook`?

Comment: Btw I hope you meant `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`?

Comment: @Tarang Yup you are right, its `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`. `mrt add accounts-password` made the login widget appear! It appears to be misaligned though, is that normal?

Comment: this is the correct behaviour. You have to customize the final bit of how you want it to come out. (it doesn't assume you're going to use it in a navbar)

Comment: What did you do to get the nice white dropdown instead of the blue link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To whoever finds this and wonders why this is happening, the solution is pretty simple. Just remove the standard accounts-ui package from meteor by typing `meteor remove accounts-ui`. Apparently the standard package overrides the CSS classes of the bootstrap-3 styled accounts ui.

Answer (score 3):

You have to leave out the LI element around *{{loginButtons}}*.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    {{loginButtons}}
  </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Additionally, you need a package like accounts-facebook, accounts-password or accounts-google.

```
mrt add accounts-twitter
```

Comment: This was the missing piece for me. I had already removed accounts-ui. So removing the <li> was the missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the element, you may notice:

```
#login-buttons {
    display: none;
}
```

This was the problem I had, although, I don't know why it is set to `display: none`.

Comment: i found *two* rules declaring the .dropdown-menu element display: none. after i changed this it was showing up. the thing seems messy in more than one way.

Answer (score 1):

I also accidentally had both the `bootstrap` and `bootstrap 3` packages installed, which was breaking the css. I did `$ meteor remove bootstrap` and everything works now. Stupid mistake, but maybe it'll help someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>{{ loginButtons }}</li>
```

The problem here is you forget to use `>` "greater than sign", therefore it should be:

```
{{> loginButtons }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem because of `useraccounts:bootstrap` package conflicting with this package.

Remove all packages (can be achieved through `meteor remove` or by adding `#` in front of package name in .meteor/packages) and then enable packages one by one. You'll know the package causing conflict. Then remove the conflicting package using `meteor remove {packagename}`